# Why is my Angular component loadable within a module where the component is not declared and that does not import the module where it is declared?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have two modules (`AppModule` and `SomeModule`) and one component (`SomeComponent`).

`SomeComponent` is declared inside `SomeModule` :

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [SomeComponent, SomeOtherComponent],
})
export class SomeModule { }
```

Inside `AppModule` there is no `SomeComponent` declaration and no `SomeModule` import.

I also have two routing modules, one for each module (`AppRoutingModule` for `AppModule` and `SomeRoutingModule` for `SomeModule`).

`AppRoutingModule`:

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: `some_path/new`, component: SomeComponent },
  { path: `some_path/:id`, loadChildren: () => import('./some/some.module').then((m) => m.SomeModule) },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, )],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

`SomeRoutingModule`:

```
export const someRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'do_edition', component: SomeComponent },
  { path: 'do_something_else', component: SomeOtherComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(someRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class SomeRoutingModule { }
```

With this routings, I can load `SomeComponent` with 2 routes:

- `some_path/new`
- `some_path/:id/do_edition`

It is what I want, and it works : no problem. :)

But I don't understand why it is working : I would have expect the `some_path/new` not to work. How `SomeComponent` can be loaded if it is declared in `SomeModule` and if `AppModule` doesn't import `SomeModule` ?

Is it `loadChildren: () => import('./some/some.module')` the explanation? I don't think it is, because it is done for the other path (`path:` some_path/:id`).

I think I don't understand all the lazy loading module logic...

Thank you

---

UPDATE: here is the stackblitz you requested @bryan60, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bragva?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Comment: something else is going on where you're accidentally importing `SomeModule` somewhere else. the situation as described here wouldn't even compile in current angular version

Comment: @bryan60 I agree. But there are only 2 occurences of the `SomeModule` wording in the whole project: `export class TestComponent` + `import('./some/some.module').then((m) => m.SomeModule)`. I have reproduced my issue in a very basic similar context: the root module `AppModule` and it's associated routing module do not change (it means the global context is still the one of my app), but aside I have especially created basic files (1 module, 1 routing module, 1 component). => The component stills load. I start to wonder if the root module coule be particular and be able to load any component?

Comment: @bryan60 I continued to investigate using the test context described in my previous comment: even if I remove the declaration of the component inside the module, the root module is still able to load the component. The component is declared nowhere, but is loadable... There is something I don't understand.

Comment: @bryan60 I tried the almost same context as the one described in my original post, but this time the main module (the one whose routing module contains a path that links to the component, and within whom no declaration of the component is made) is not the app root module. The component still loads... If the component is declared nowhere (see my second comment) : the component stills loads...

Comment: you should make a stackblitz cause you're missing something.

Comment: @bryan60 : I added it at the end of the original post

Comment: This is not an issue or bug, but expected behavior

Comment: @bryan60 do you confirm what Siddhant wrote? How is my stackblitz different from the description in my original post? If it's the expected behavior, it's perfect for me. But it would mean I don't understand the point of declaring components inside modules. Is the component declaration only useful when writing a package (let's say an Angular project installed a package, inside whom a component has to loadable by the Angular project) ?

Comment: The point of declaring components inside modules is defining the compilation scope. For the scenario wherein you didn't declared component inside any NgModule, try using `ngIf` or `ngFor` within it's template and see what happens. Do the component load without any issues? Are those directives recognized?

Comment: @Siddhant : using my initial example, if I add the `ngIf` directive in `SomeComponent` template, it fails. But if I import `CommonModule` in `SomeModule`, then it works for both routes `some_path/new` and `some_path/:id/do_edition`. Yet, the route `some_path/new` is not handled by `SomeModule`/`SomeRoutingModule` but by `AppModule`/`AppRoutingModule`. The question remains the same: how `AppModule`/`AppRoutingModule` succeed in loading `SomeComponent` and importing `CommonModule` without importing `SomeModule`?